# HTTPS request slow, caused by ssl certificate

Tags: python, ubuntu, ssl, python-requests, ubuntu-22.04

```py
import requests
import threading
import time

def req():
    s = time.time()
    r = requests.get('https://www.google.com/')
    e = time.time()
    response_times.append(e - s)

response_times = []
thread_amount = 50
print(f"{thread_amount} parallel threads")
threads = []
s1 = time.time()
for i in range(thread_amount):
    threads.append(threading.Thread(target = req))  
s2 = time.time()
for thread in threads:
    thread.start()
s3 = time.time()
for thread in threads:
    thread.join()
s4 = time.time()

total_time = s4 - s1
spawn_time = s2 -s1
start_time = s3 -s2
finish_time = s4 -s3
average_time_per_thread = sum(response_times) / len(response_times)

print(f"average response time per request: {average_time_per_thread} s")
print(f"total time: {total_time} s")
print(f"spawn time: {spawn_time} s")
print(f"start time: {start_time} s")
print(f"finish time: {finish_time} s")
```

The average response time per request is 5.5 sec for 50 parallel threads/requests. I already know that the problem has something to do with SSL certificates, for 100+ parallel requests I get an error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/requests/adapters.py", line 439, in send
    resp = conn.urlopen(
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 755, in urlopen
    retries = retries.increment(
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/urllib3/util/retry.py", line 574, in increment
    raise MaxRetryError(_pool, url, error or ResponseError(cause))
urllib3.exceptions.MaxRetryError: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='www.google.com', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: / (Caused by SSLError(SSLZeroReturnError(6, 'TLS/SSL connection has been closed (EOF) (_ssl.c:997)')))

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.10/threading.py", line 1009, in _bootstrap_inner
    self.run()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.10/threading.py", line 946, in run
    self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
  File "/root/speedtest.py", line 7, in req
    r = requests.get('https://www.google.com/')
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/requests/api.py", line 76, in get
    return request('get', url, params=params, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/requests/api.py", line 61, in request
    return session.request(method=method, url=url, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/requests/sessions.py", line 542, in request
    resp = self.send(prep, **send_kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/requests/sessions.py", line 655, in send
    r = adapter.send(request, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/requests/adapters.py", line 514, in send
    raise SSLError(e, request=request)
requests.exceptions.SSLError: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='www.google.com', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: / (Caused by SSLError(SSLZeroReturnError(6, 'TLS/SSL connection has been closed (EOF) (_ssl.c:997)')))
```

This issue occured right after I did the following on my ubuntu 22.04 server:

`sudo snap install core; sudo snap refresh core`-
`sudo snap install --classic certbot`-
`sudo ln -s /snap/bin/certbot /usr/bin/certbot`-
`sudo apt-get install nginx`-
`sudo certbot --nginx` (at this step I had to create a certificate for my domain)-
`sudo certbot renew --dry-run`

Before that, the average response time per request was 0.45 sec.
It seems that I crashed the SSL certificate for python requests, but I don't know the file which cause this problem.
If I change the request to `requests.get('https://www.google.com/', verify=False)`, the average response time will be 0.45 sec again, but I think this is not a good solution.

Comment: have you tried with `verify=False` for requests to confirm it is the case?

Comment: Yes I also added this to the initial post now, with `verify = False`, the average response time will be 0.45 sec again.

Comment: try exporting the REQUESTS_CA_BUNDLE env variable directly. example: `export REQUESTS_CA_BUNDLE='path/to/cert/file'`

Comment: How to I get the path to the cert file?

Comment: I assume you already had one saved on your local system - is that not the case?

Comment: there is a certificate `/etc/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt`, but not sure if I should use this.

Comment: some googling reveals that certbot saves certificates to `/etc/letsencrypt/live/`. Im not sure if that's the case however.

Comment: not too sure either, but I guess you can try with that as well.

Comment: Okay I executed your command in powershell with path `/etc/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt`, but what happened now?

Comment: nothing much, that env variable is used by the `requests` library when you run the code. so you could try to run the script again without `verify=False`, and check if it's any faster.

Comment: It is still slow. I also tried to delete `/etc/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt`, which lead to this error `OSError: Could not find a suitable TLS CA certificate bundle, invalid path: /etc/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt`. After creating a new one with `sudo update-ca-certificates`, it is still as slow as before.

Comment: so you installed a bunch of libraries, and one of them were the culprit for the slowness. i would work my way back and figure out which one is causing the issue. for instance, does certbot install any local certificates? if so, where is the path where it installs certs? if you are able to find where they are located, you could similarly set the env variable and try again. or else, just try deleting the certs and see if it resolves the issue.

Comment: But with your command I made python requests to use the certificate from the path, right? So why should any other certificate cause the issue, if `/etc/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt` is used?

Comment: I'm thinking that it is not the default cert, so maybe requests is looking at other certs. not sure how to debug which one it is using though.

Comment: oh wow I just resettet my ubuntu server and made a fresh ubuntu 22 installation. Now I noticed that it is already that slow with a fresh installation. I just upgraded from ubuntu 20 to 22, with 20 there was no issue at all.

Comment: Try with a lower level tool: `openssl s_client -connect www.google.com:443` , if it is slow, inspect the output or compare it with other machine where it works. I do recommend to try separately for IPv4 and IPv6 (options `-4` and `-6`). Delays like in your case are sometimes caused by trying IPv6 first and falling back to IPv4 if the IPv6 networking is not configured properly (result of https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Happy_Eyeballs)

Comment: +1 to @VPfB comment. A lower level too will show you exactly which TLS record breaks the handshake. It might not be certificate related at all.

Comment: "This issue occured right after I did the following on my ubuntu 22.04 server:" None of certbot or nginx updates should have an impact on your attempts to contact external hosts using HTTPS